# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, faq, site-scope

Quite simply, what should it contain?

To help with lots of answers, if you can format as follows, please and thank you:

Answers:

- Put headings in either **bold** or
- #### Third level heading format

with answers as normal.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Super User FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about ...
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

We could just use this as a guide with tweaks for our site. Here's an example:

> Apple Stack Exchange is for Apple enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - Apple hardware
> - Apple software
> - other Apple products or services
>
> and it is not about ...
>
> - Apple Developer Programs or programming, with the exception of AppleScript and Automator
> - installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

We need to flesh out the two sections a bit more, but it's a start.

Comment: I don't think enough of a consensus on hackintosh questions was ever reached to call it out specifically in the faq.  Plus we haven't really had problems with that anyway.  Otherwise, looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @Kyle - re programming we should add bash/other shell scripting as simple ones are off topic on SO

Answer (score 2):

#### Summarise the overlap/distinction between Ask Different and Super User

To seasoned users of both stacks, the overlap/distinction may be obvious.

Newcomers might appreciate a more upfront one-line summary (amongst FAQ) helping them to deciding which stack will be most appropriate for their question.

**Notes**

At http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1491219#1491219

> I guess that I should *promote* Ask Different, whilst *maintaining awareness* of Super User and the overlap.

Adapted from my line at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1491276#1491276

> A user might view iPad as a *computer*, but Super User ([for *computer* enthusiasts and power users](https://superuser.com/faq)) prefers iPad questions elsewhere, because iOS was primarily *phone*-oriented.

[How can I help promote Ask Different as a new version of OS X is released?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589/8546) (2011-07-20) encourages questions "no matter how silly", which is, I guessed aimed at seasoned users who know [where to draw the line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) with silliness :-)