# Now that iOS 5 is out, help promote Ask Different

Tags: discussion

Now that iOS 5 is shipping, there will be zillions of iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch users upgrading, and they'll have lots of questions. And since all those questions will be new, Ask Different will have as good a shot at having the best answer than any of those, you know, competitive sites. Essentially, this is a great time to recruit new members!

What can you do to help?

As you install and learn iOS 5, whenever you have questions, no matter how silly, ask them here. You're not the only one having that question. Millions of other people will, too. Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself... and if you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself.

When answering iOS 5 questions, do everything you can to overkill it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, step-by-step, ultra-clear guide with screenshots and examples. Help us have the best possible answer to the common problems and questions people have with iOS 5.

If a question comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly formatted, or in bad English, edit it into shape. We've always encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make every question into a full sentence.

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to common iOS 5 questions that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as the rest of the iPhone universe upgrades. Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Ask Different continues to have great answers like we have in the past, we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

(If this post looks familiar, it's because it's nearly identical to [the one Joel posted](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/now-that-lion-is-out-help-promote-ask-different) when Lion first came out. The rule still applies! Let's do it!)